# Arduino Voltage Divider Wrong Voltage

Tags: arduino, mosfet, voltage-divider

I have a Arduino Pin connected to a Logic Level MosFet (IRF3708) to switch a 12V led strip which should consume 1A. The Ugs(th) voltage of the MosFet is 2V. That I don't accidentally kill one of my MosFets I put a voltage divider at the output of the arduino. It should give me a voltage of 2.04V but I just get 1.6V. The arduino pin and the MosFet gate should be high impedance and I don't understand why?

**Schematic**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftuoFM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There is a schematic drawing tool button on the editor toolbar. Please draw a schematic rather than describe a circuit in words.

Comment: Maximum Gate to Source voltage is 12V. No need to put resistive divider to drive its gate with arduino.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know there was a tool in the forum. Sorry for that.

Comment: When I connected the Arduino pin directly to the MosFet it fried after some seconds and I thought I exceeded the max. Ugs voltage.

Comment: Are you going to switch a relay?

Comment: I tried to switch a led strip with ~1A @12V. If i switch just for a couple of seconds it works but if i switch continiously the MosFet dies.

Comment: Did you not know 2V is the threshold for high resistance at low current? You Always need 2.5 to 3x this max Vgs(th) as a minimum!

Comment: perhaps a better question to ask is "Why do I keep killing my MOSFETs?" since that is the root problem.

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage?  What instrument are you using?  A voltmeter with too low a resistance will cause the voltage to be lower.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Now I know this but then I have another problem.

Comment: @Frosty I thought the same but I didn't want so leave everyone here unnoticed. But as this problem is solved I open another one for my MosFet problem.

Comment: @KevinWhite A cheap but trusty multimeter. But with WhatRoughBeast's explaination below I got what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is the Arduino pin going to 4 volts, rather than 5. Have you measured it?

With that said, you are going about your gate drive in exactly the wrong way. You should not put any sort of divider before your gate. You need to understand the FET specs much more than you do. The upper limit on Vgs(th) is not a do-not-exceed limit. Rather, it is a minimum requirement. Worse, if you look closely at the data sheet, you will see that this level is specified to produce a drain current level of something like 250 uA or 1 mA, neither of which is remotely adequate for your load. For normal loads, you should provide at least 3 times the upper Vgs(th). In this case, if your load requires relatively little current you might get away with 5 volts. Then again, you might not.

EDIT - Since you have verified that the Arduino pin goes to 4.92 volts, the most likely culprit is your meter. 1 Megohm is the standard input impedance. Consider its effect on the circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnAqcj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

which is close enough to your 1.6. And if your resistors are not 1% tolerance, such tolerances could easily explain what difference remains.

Comment: I have read about that. But I fried some of my MosFets after driving them directly with the Arduino and thought I put a too high voltage on the gate. The load was a led stripe with ~1A @12V and I don't get how I destroyed it then.

Comment: And the Arduino voltage was 4.92V.

Comment: @moessi774 - Are you sure you've tied your +5 and +12 grounds together?

Comment: @moessi774 - See edit.

Comment: Yes I put the grounds together. But your explaination is logical. I calculated the same divider including my before used 1MOhm pull down I had on the gate and wondered why this is the same voltage which I read with the multimeter but without the pull-down resistor. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: Your math doesn't check out (470 || 1M = 469.78). ok It looks like you were calculating 470 || 1k instead.

Comment: @Frosty - Please look at the diagram again. 1M in parallel with 470k, not 470.

Comment: Gadzooks. I didn't notice the suffixes.

Answer (score 0):

Vgs(th) is the voltage at which the MOSFET turns on, not the maximum Gate-Source voltage the part can tolerate.

Maximum Vgs is given in the "Absolute Maximum Ratings" table of [the datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3708.pdf) and is +/-12V so you don't need to "protect" the gate from the voltage level of your Arduino.

As to why your voltage divider doesn't work as expected: Have you verified your component values and your source voltage?

Comment: I have read about that. But I fried some of my MosFets after driving them directly with the Arduino and thought I put a too high voltage on the gate. What could have destroyed the MosFet then? The load is a stripe of Leds which should pull ~1A @12V.

Comment: @moessi774 You have no idea how to select MOSFTs And the answers are duplicated on this site for Vgs, Ciss, effects on Resistance and rise time

Comment: I am new to MosFets I know. But I want to learn it and accept my failures when I try to. What do you mean by duplicate answers?